# Touch/drag motion to select multiple cells in a lazyvgrid

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use a `LazyVGrid` in SwiftUI where you can touch and drag your finger to select multiple adjacent cells in a specific order. This is not drag and drop, and I don't want to move the cells (maybe drag isn't the right term here, but couldn't think of another one to describe it). Also, you would be able to reverse the selection (ie: each cell can only be selected once and reversing direction would un-select the cell). How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var cellsArray: CellsArray
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: spacing) {
                ForEach(0..<(rows * columns), id: \.self){index in
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        CellsView(index: index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct CellsView: View {
            
    @State var index: Int
    @EnvironmentObject var cellsArray: CellsArray

    var body: some View {
       ZStack {
           Text("\(self.cellsArray[index].cellValue)") //cellValue is a string
               .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
               .frame(width: getWidth(), height: getWidth())
               .background(Color.gray)
       }
       //.onTapGesture ???
    }
    func getWidth()->CGFloat{
                
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 10
        
        return width / CGFloat(columns)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not look you even tried. This can be helpful to start https://stackoverflow.com/a/63438481/12299030.

Comment: Drag gesture would be more appropriate. Does your grid can scroll ? Something like Photos app ?

Comment: No, it doesn't scroll. It's more like a board game.

Comment: I don't want to move the cells, just drag your finger to select them in a specific order and also reverse the drag motion to unselect.

Comment: Reworded the question, hopefully it's more clear

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution. The subviews read their coordinates (in the coordinate system of the parent view) and transmit them to the parent view, while the `DragGesture` uses these coordinates for determining which subviews the rectangle spanned by the drag operation touches:

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    static let numSubviews = 18
    
    let subviews = [Text](repeating: Text("אבגד"), count: numSubviews)

    @State
    var selectedSubviews = Set<Int>()
    
    var rectangles = Rectangles()

    @State
    var selectRect: CGRect?

    var body: some View
    {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            LazyVGrid(
                columns: [GridItem](repeating: GridItem(.fixed(40)), count: 3),
                content: {
                    ForEach(0 ..< subviews.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        subviews[i]
                            .background() {
                                GeometryReader { gp -> Color in
                                    rectangles.content[i] = gp.frame(in: .named("container"))
                                    return Color.clear
                                }
                            }
                            .border(Color.green, width: selectedSubviews.contains(i) ? 1 : 0)
                    }
                }
            )
                .coordinateSpace(name: "container")
                .gesture(dragSelect)
            
            if let selR = selectRect {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: selR.width, height: selR.height)
                    .offset(x: selR.origin.x, y: selR.origin.y)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var dragSelect: some Gesture
    {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 2)
            .onChanged() { drag in
                let a = drag.startLocation
                let b = drag.location
                
                selectRect = CGRect(x: min(a.x, b.x), y: min(a.y, b.y), width: abs(a.x - b.x), height: abs(a.y - b.y))
                
                var resSet = Set<Int>()
        
                for i in 0 ..< ContentView.numSubviews {
                    if CGRectIntersectsRect(rectangles.content[i]!, selectRect!) {
                        resSet.insert(i)
                    }
                }
                selectedSubviews = resSet
            }
            .onEnded() { _ in
                selectRect = nil
            }
    }
}

/// A map `[Int : CGRect]` without the nasty copy-on-assignment behavior.
class Rectangles
{
    var content = [Int : CGRect]()
}
```

The trick of reading the coordinates in the `background` `View` modifier is a slight modification of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61357592/9109340. It helps to prevent view distortion that wrapping the subview in a `GeometryReader` could cause (for more complex subviews than in this example).

The border of the subview serves for visualizing which subviews are selected, the optional `Rectangle` in the `ZStack` for showing the user the area spanned by the drag operation.

Using `@State var rectangles: [Int : CGRect]` instead of `var rectangles: Rectangles` does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might help, the only issue here is the coordinate space. Overlay is not drawing the rectangle in the correct coordinate space.

```
struct ImagesView: View {
    var columnSize: CGFloat
    @Binding var projectImages: [ProjectImage]
    @State var selectedImages: [ImageSelection] = []
    @State var dragWidth: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var dragHeight: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var dragStart: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200), spacing: 0)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader() { geometry in
            ZStack{
                ScrollView{
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [
                        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: columnSize), spacing: 2)
                    ], spacing: 2){
                        ForEach(projectImages, id: \.imageUUID){ image in
                            Image(nsImage: NSImage(data: image.imageData)!)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .border(selectedImages.contains(where: {imageSelection in imageSelection.uuid == image.imageUUID}) ? Color.blue : .primary, width: selectedImages.contains(where: {imageSelection in imageSelection.uuid == image.imageUUID}) ? 5.0 : 1.0)
                                
                                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded{
                                    print("Double tap finished")
                                })
                                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 1).onEnded{
                                    if selectedImages.contains(where: {imageSelection in imageSelection.uuid == image.imageUUID}) {
                                        print("Image is already selected")
                                        if let index = selectedImages.firstIndex(where: {imageSelection in imageSelection.uuid == image.imageUUID}){
                                            selectedImages.remove(at: index)
                                        }
                                        
                                    } else {
                                        selectedImages.append(ImageSelection(imageUUID: image.imageUUID))
                                        print("Image has been selected")
                                    }
                                })
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(minHeight: 50)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 1)
                }
                .simultaneousGesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 2)
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            print("Drag Start: \(value.startLocation.x)")
                            self.dragStart = value.startLocation
                            self.dragWidth = value.translation.width
                            self.dragHeight = value.translation.height
                        })
                )
                .overlay{
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: dragWidth, height: dragHeight)
                        .offset(x:dragStart.x, y:dragStart.y)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```