# SwiftUI: Selecting multiple items with a two-finger pan gesture

Tags: swift, uitableview, swiftui, uicollectionview, drag

`UITableView` and `UICollectionView` has a 2-finger drag to select multiple items. Is there a SwiftUI equivalent or a custom solution to achieve this? I don't see anything in the documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/selecting_multiple_items_with_a_two-finger_pan_gesture

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71851665/5133585).

Comment: I didn't know there was this kind of gesture. For most cases, when you need multiple selection, the most common way is to enable edit mode first, then use one finger move over the items.